# Simple object value retrieval

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a object returned to me from an API that holds this- `{ "query1": 0.443}`

I'm trying to get out the 0.443 by using:

```
request(options, function (error, response, body)
            {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);
            var moo = 'query1';
            var cow = body[moo];
            console.log(cow);
```

But the value is showing up as undefined. What am I forgetting?

Comment: Make that `var body =`, not `Obj Body =`

Comment: Sorry I should state that the body is being returned by an API

Comment: You have a typo B and b are two different things ans this two different variables names.

Comment: @Katserbot: Then post your whole code, not the part that is working.

Comment: @Bergi I posted the request function from my node.js, its weird because when I run the script, it shows me the { "query1": 0.443} in it's entirety when I console.log(body);

Comment: @Katserbot: Maybe you forgot to parse it? Is `typeof body` still string? Then use `JSON.parse(body)[moo]`

Answer (score 0):

```
var body = { "query1": 0.443 };
var moo = 'query1';
var cow = body[ moo ];
console.log(cow);
```

Or you can simply just use dot notation to access the property

```
var body = { "query1": 0.443 };
console.log( body.query1 );
```

Comment: Or rather, `body` not `Body`. Non-constructors should be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple:

```
var data = { "query1": 0.443 }

console.log(data.query1)
```

So, if your object is returned as say an ajax response named data, simply

```
var myVal = data.query1
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are really good ways to get values in objects using keys! I had forgotten to use JSON.parse on the object an API returned back to me!

```
request(options, function (error, response, body)
        {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        var holder = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(holder.query1);
```

Thanks to everyone who answered! Cheers!